# auto add number at end of variable

Tags: php

i have this variable

```
$n= "";
```

it can be 1 or 2   example:  $n= "1"; or $n= "2";

so i want $number to be changed to $number1 or $number2 so it will get 1 or 2 from $n

```
 $live = ($number1-$r3) / 60;
```

so i have tried like this but dont work

```
  $n= "1";
 $lv = "$number".$n;    
  $live = ($lv-$r3) / 60;
```

so in this case it need to be   $live = ($number1-$r3) / 60;

i dont know if there is a way to do this, if u didnt understeand question u can comment below

Comment: You start by talking about `$n` and finish by talking about `$number` please be logical

Comment: in $n i add the number that need to be after $number
n and number are different

Answer (score 2):

```
${'number' . $n}
```

this will be $number1 or $number2

Comment: You made an answer yourself. You mean you got the solution and posting the answer?

Answer (score 0):

To add a number to the end of a variable in PHP you can do something like this:

```
<?php
$theVariableName="\$number";
for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
    echo "theVariableName is now:".$theVariableName."<br />";      //debug text
    echo "now we add a number.<br />";                            //debug text
    $theVariableName="\$number".$i;                              //actual solution
    echo "New theVariableName is now:".$theVariableName."<br />"; //debug text
    echo "<br /><br />";                                          //debug text
}
?>
```

The End Result Would Output this:

> theVariableName is now:$number0
>   now we add a number.
>   New theVariableName is now:$number1

...

> theVariableName is now:$number8
>   now we add a number.
>   New theVariableName is now:$number9